# Как загрузить в бд html код?

Tags: python

Мне нужно добавить html код в mysql, но он не добавляется из-за кавычек. Я попробовал экранировать их, но ошибка не уходит

```
def create_connection(host_name, user_name, user_password, db_name):
    connection = None
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host_name,
            user=user_name,
            passwd=user_password,
            database=db_name
        )
        return connection

    cn = create_connection("localhost", "root", "root", "Blog")
    cur = cn.cursor()
    
        
        
        stmt_date = (title, text, price)
        stmt_query = """
                    INSERT INTO
                    `Products` (`title`, `text`, `price`)
                    VALUES
                    (%s, %s, null, %s);
                """
        cur.execute(stmt_query, stmt_date)
```

Comment: Нужно не изобретать велосипеды, а использовать способы экранирования, предусмотренные используемой вами библиотекой для работы с mysql

Comment: @andreymal Мне все равно выдает ошибку `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'div class=\'top-image-holder\'><img src=\'/uploads/images/img/13.jpg\'></' at line 4`

Comment: Покажите код, который выдаёт ошибку

Comment: @andreymal Я обновил код

Comment: У вас в sql-запросе в первой паре скобок указаны 3 имени столбцов, а во второй паре скобок почему-то 4 значения вместе с null, нестыковочка

Comment: @andreymal я убрал null, но ошибка не ушла